# How to prove that two series converge simultaneously?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Do $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} n(a_n -a_{n+1})$ converge simultaneously?

$$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} n(a_n -a_{n+1}) = a_1 - a_2 + 2a_2 -2a_3 + 3a_3-3a_4  + ... = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$$

It looks like they could possible differ by some term $-a_{n+1}$, but I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Take $a_n = 1$ which diverges but $n(a_n - a_{n+1}) = 0$ converges. Am i missing something?

Comment: @eminem Ok, but here above I have rewritten the second series so that it looks like the first one, so it should behave equally. What's the error in the equation?

Comment: You cant rearrange, take brackets off or on when a series diverges. Here, $a_n$ diverges, so you cant do anything with it. Take a look at [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

If you write the partial sums up to $n=N$ for the two series you will see that they differ by $NA_{N+1}$. If you assume that $na_n \to 0$ then the two series both converge or both diverge. But in general this is not true as the  example by eminem shows. Your mistake is in manipulating infinite sums without even knowing their convergence.